# Resolve No owin.Environment item was found in the context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin

I have found many threads discussing this problem but getting any of them to work has eluded me so far.

I have been trying to follow [ProDinner](https://prodinner.codeplex.com/) as a way of learning how to implement role based authentication in my app. But I cannot work out what I am missing. Every time I try to log in I get

> No owin.Environment item was found in the context

After a lot of debugging and searching I have found the `Startup` class is not being called. I've tried to resolve by stepping through the proDinner code to see, how `Startup` is being called and googled (a lot!). My searches lead me to adding (although neither exist in the proDinner project)

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="Tjs.Startup, Tjs" />
```

then

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="Tjs.Web.Admin.Startup, Tjs" />
```

Below I have added all of what I believe is the relevant code, but please let me know if I am missing anything.

The AccountController is a copy paste of ProDinner, with the addition of a parameterless constructor, I was unable to work out how that parameter is being passed in the Prodinner project (could that be the problem?)

**Tjs**: solution name

**Tjs.Web.Admin**: namespace

**Owin packages**

```
<package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
```

**root of project**

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

using Tjs.Web.Admin;
using Tjs.Web.Admin.App_Start;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace Tjs.Web.Admin
{
  public class Startup
  {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OwinConfig.ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
  }
}
```

**App_Start**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Owin;
namespace Tjs.Web.Admin.App_Start
{
  public static class OwinConfig
  {
    public static void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/SignIn")
        });
    }
  }
}
```

**AccountController**

```
    private readonly IUserService userService;
    public AccountController()
    {

    }

    public AccountController(IUserService userService)
    {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    private IAuthenticationManager Authentication
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
    }

    private void SignInOwin(string name, bool rememberMe, string role)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name) },
            DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);

        //foreach (var role in roles)
        //{
        //    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        //}
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));

        Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            IsPersistent = rememberMe
        }, identity);
    }

    public ActionResult SignIn()
    {
        return View(new SignIn { Email = "o", Password = "1" });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SignIn(SignIn input)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            input.Password = null;
            input.Email = null;
            return View(input);
        }

        Staff staff;

        //ACHTUNG: remove this in a real app
        if (input.Email == "o" && input.Password == "1")
        {
            staff = new Staff { Email = "o", Role = new Role { Description = "admin" } };
        }
        else
        {
            staff = userService.Get(input.Email, input.Password);
        }

        if (staff == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Try Login: o and Password: 1");
            return View();
        }

        SignInOwin(staff.Email, input.Remember, staff.Role.Description);


        return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
    }

    public ActionResult SignOff()
    {
        Authentication.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("SignIn", "Account");
    }
}
```

it fails at

```
private IAuthenticationManager Authentication
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to add this to youe `web.config`  `<appSettings><add key="owin:AppStartup" value="[Namespace].Startup, [AssemblyName]" /></appSettings> `

Comment: What am I missing? I thought that is one of the things I had tried? (mentioned near the top of my post)

Comment: `key="owin:AppStartup"`

Comment: THANKYOU!!!! I must have gone blind at some point, I cant believe I didnt spot that. My assembly name was also wrong!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your `web.config`  `<appSettings><add key="owin:AppStartup" value="[Namespace].Startup, [AssemblyName]" /></appSettings>`

Comment: I also needed to add the Startup.cs class file to my project (Right-click Project > Add > Class > search for Owin Startup class and name 'Startup.cs')

Comment: I also had to delete <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" /> as mentioned in stackoverflow.com/questions/18232549/… in Mathi Rajan's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I added a new key `owin:AutomaticAppStartup` to WebConfig in order to the Startup class to be loaded automatically.

```
<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="[Namespace].Startup,[AssemblyName]" />
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added  into the "web.config"

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

Comment: Where did you put this? It doesn't work as a child element directly under the `<configuration>` element.

Comment: Pardon me, I spoke too soon. I saw the red error underline and assumed it was complaining about an out-of-place element. In fact, the problem was that the tag wasn't closed: `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />`. So it does go directly under the `<configuration>` element.