# Owin Environment not found in context

Tags: c#, owin, asp.net-mvc-5

I am building an MVC 5 app.

In my startup.cs file I have

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ForexRebatesNowEntities>(() => new ForexRebatesNowEntities());
    CreateRolesandUsers();
}
private void CreateRolesandUsers()
{
    ForexRebatesNowEntities db = new ForexRebatesNowEntities();
    var roleManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<RoleManager<UserRole, int>>();
```

My Code fails with the following error when I try and run the site

> No owin.Environment item was found in the context

My understanding is the I have added ForexRebateEntitieNow (Entity Framework connection) to the owin context, but the code fails when I try and instantiate a roleManager.

How can I ensure my Owin start up?

Comment: HttpContext does not exists yet on start up. which is where you are trying to access it. it only exists in a request. If you try to access it at startup you will get the error you described

Comment: Ah ok, excellent. I didnt realise that. IF you want to make that an answer I will accept it. I dont suppose you know of a way of accessing the current context other than how I attempted?

Comment: I'll check. i would also recommend checking out this answer to see it that may actually be the cause of the issue. while I am sure that httpcontext does not exist at startup this my help is your overall problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/35565781/5233410